# Detect-all does not affect output-decimal-marker (siunitx)

Tags: siunitx

I would like `siunitx` to detect the document font family and use it for numbers in an `S` tabular cell, so I am using the `detect-all` option, which however does not seem to affect the output decimal marker (which I have set to a comma to spot the difference more easily). Using parentheses as in the first row obviously negatively affects the alignment and is counterproductive. Enlighten me as usually, please. :-)

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\sisetup{
detect-all,
output-decimal-marker = {,}
}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\begin{longtable}{| S[table-text-alignment = center, table-format = 2.2] |}
\hline
{Foo} \\ \hline
1,23 \\
45,67 \\ \hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: @Joseph Wright Could you please tell me whether this is a feature? If yes, what practical use does it have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Harold: Instead of `output-decimal-marker = {,}`, try setting `output-decimal-marker = \text{.}` -- or `... = \text{,}` if you want it to be a comma.

Comment: Harold: I learned this trick from Joseph Wright!